# Impersonate another user when connecting to SQL database

Tags: teamcity, powershell-2.0

What is the best way of impersonating another user when connecting to a SQL database on TeamCity/in general? For instance, if the `env.USERNAME`/`[Environment]::UserName` is different to the one you which you use.

I've tried the following, and it fails to connect to the database on each attempt (`$varSQLServer` is null). Am I doing something wrong? I've been working on the same lines of code for days. Please note due to resource constraints, I am using Powershell 2.

```
function connectToDb() {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String]$varDBUser
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String]$varDBPassword
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String]$varDBServer
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String]$varDBInstance
    )     

    [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null 
    $varSQLServer = New-Object -typeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -argumentList "$varDBServer\$varDBInstance"
    $varSQLServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $true 
    $varSQLServer.ConnectionContext.ConnectAsUser = $false 
    $varSQLServer.ConnectionContext.ConnectAsUserName  = $varDBUser 
    $varSQLServer.ConnectionContext.ConnectAsUserPassword = $varDBPassword

    try {
        varSQLServer.ConnectionContext.Connect()
    }
    catch {
        throw "Can't connect to SQL Server".
        Write-Error $_
        [System.Environment]::Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code in in C#.NET hope it helps you to understand the concept.

```
    var srvConnectionConn = new ServerConnection("WIN-DVGQDI73QR6");

srvConnectionConn.ConnectAsUser = true;
srvConnectionConn.ConnectAsUserName = @"administrator@mva";
srvConnectionConn.ConnectAsUserPassword = "*****";

srvConnectionConn.ConnectTimeout = 60;
srvConnectionConn.NonPooledConnection = true;

Server srv = new Server(srvConnectionConn);
```

I am trying to connect using domain admin acc mva\Administrator